# passing variable to a function

Tags: vbscript

its kind of silly question. but i dont know what mistake i am making. if any one could help.

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text /vbscript">  
function zips(s)  
  document.write(s)  
end function   
</script>  
</head>  

<body>  
<script type="text/vbscript">  
 dim x,y  
 x="sushant"  
<button onclick="zips(x)" id=button1 name=button1>clickme</button>  
</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

sorry i dont know how to format it. but i am no getting the desired output. any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `button` tag should be *outside* of the `script` tag.

```
<script type="text/vbscript">  
 dim x,y  
 x="sushant"  
</script>  
<button onclick="zips(x)" id=button1 name=button1>clickme</button>
```

The button is not part of the script but part of the HTML.